# Load images to listview dynamically

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scroll

I'm having 4 groups of contacts(Type1,2,3,None). i want to load different images 3 for Type1,2,3, if contact belong to None then listview shouldn't contain any image.. This is my code

```
@Override       
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
ViewGroup parent) {             
// return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) ContactsListActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_row_view, null);
        }

        try {
            contactsData = (ContactsItem) getItem(position);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (null != contactsData){
            final CheckBox contactsSelectedCheck = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_selected_check);
            TextView contactNameText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_name_text);
            TextView contactNumberText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_number_text);
            ImageView contactImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);

            contactNameText.setText(contactsData.getContactName());
            contactNumberText.setText(contactsData.getContactNumber());             

            if(contactNameText != null && contactNumberText != null){
            if(contactsData.getContactProfileType() == DBConstants.TYPE_1){                 contactImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_1));
            } else if(contactsData.getContactProfileType() == DBConstants.TYPE_2){                  contactImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_2));
            } else if(contactsData.getContactProfileType() == DBConstants.TYPE_3){                  contactImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_3));
            }else{

            }
            }

            if (selectedContactsTable.containsKey(contactsData.getContactNumber())) {
                contactsSelectedCheck.setChecked(true);             
            } else {
                contactsSelectedCheck.setChecked(false);                
            }

            contactsSelectedCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (contactsSelectedCheck.isChecked()) {
                        LinearLayout r_layout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
                        TextView contactName = (TextView) r_layout.getChildAt(1);
                        TextView contactNumber = (TextView) r_layout.getChildAt(2);
                        selectedContactsTable.put(contactNumber.getText().toString(), contactName.getText().toString());
                    }else{
                        LinearLayout r_layout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
                        TextView contactNumber = (TextView) r_layout.getChildAt(2);
                        selectedContactsTable.remove(contactNumber.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Problem with this is if i assign some contacts to Type 1 corresponding images for this type loaded correctly but when i scroll the list same image will be loaded to some unassigned also, is there any problem with my code please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the class Holder that the other question suggested. And do the Holder for every single adapter you ever create.

To answer your question, try this edit:

```
        contactImage.setVisibility(View.Visible);
       if(contactsData.getContactProfileType() == DBConstants.TYPE_1){                 contactImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_1));
        } else if(contactsData.getContactProfileType() == DBConstants.TYPE_2){                  contactImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_2));
        } else if(contactsData.getContactProfileType() == DBConstants.TYPE_3){                  contactImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_3));
        }else{
            contactImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a holder class for your views. Then in the if(v==null) block, you can use setTag() and use getTag() in the else block. Here's some code.

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView contactNameText;
    TextView contactNumberText;
    ImageView contactImage;
}
```

This is a holder class that contains your views. The first part of the getView() method should then look like this:

```
View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) ContactsListActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_row_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.contactNameText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_name_text);
        holder.contactNumberText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_number_text);
        holder.contactImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    try {
        contactsData = (ContactsItem) getItem(position);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    if (null != contactsData){
        final CheckBox contactsSelectedCheck = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_selected_check);
        holder.contactNameText.setText(contactsData.getContactName());
        holder.contactNumberText.setText(contactsData.getContactNumber());             

        if(contactNameText != null && contactNumberText != null){
        if(contactsData.getContactProfileType() == DBConstants.TYPE_1){                 holder.contactImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_1));
        } else if(contactsData.getContactProfileType() == DBConstants.TYPE_2){                  holder.contactImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_2));
        } else if(contactsData.getContactProfileType() == DBConstants.TYPE_3){                  holder.contactImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_3));
        }else{

        }
        }
```

Comment: Thank for nice approach but still same problem